# How to add a Drawable next to button's text programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I need to add an image right next to the button's text.

Using XML can I set the android:drawableEnd, but programmatically and for Api 10 I can't find the way.

I tryed with:

```
    button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, id, 0);

    button.setPadding(0, 0, rightPadding, 0);
```

but that move the text to left. I want the imagen right next to the text.

There is any way?

Thanks and sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent to `android:drawableEnd` is [`setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, id, 0)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)).

The third argument to `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()` matches up with `drawableRight`, whereas the third argument to `setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds()` matches up with `drawableEnd`.

If you are trying to adjust the padding between the drawable and the text, you should use [`setCompoundDrawablePadding(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablePadding(int)), not `setPadding()`. The latter adjusts padding for the TextView *and* the drawable as a whole, whereas the former will change the padding between the two.

**Update:**
Unfortunately you cannot set a drawable to be drawn immediately after the text in a TextView (or Button). `drawableRight` will only set a drawable to be drawn on the far right side of the TextView. If you set your Button's width to `wrap_content`, it will appear where you want, but the button obviously won't be the right width.

The best solution in this case would probably be to create a RelativeLayout that contains an ImageView and a TextView. You can style the RelativeLayout to look like a button, and set your click listener on that.

Comment: The method "setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, id, 0)" is for Api 17. I need to work with Api 10. Even so It's not working. I don't know why, but the image is not next to text. It is at the end of  button

Answer (score 1):

You could use use a `SpanneableString`.

```
yourButtonView.text = SpannableString(" ${getString(R.string.your_string)}").apply {
     setSpan(
          ImageSpan(requireContext(), R.drawable.your_icon),
          0,
          1,
          Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
     )
}
```